# how to compute the parameters of the sum of correlated gaussian variates?

Tags: distribution, gaussian, probabilistic-programming

[image]

It is trivial for the independent case.

According to Wiki, if they are correlated, the covariance of Z is [image]

the last term in the squared root is actually the covariance of X and Y, namely cov(X,Y). I just do not know how to compute this term. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Calculating ρ actually involves calculating Cov(X,Y), so your last equation is mathematically correct but not helpful.  Let's go straight for estimating the covariance.

In what follows, I'm assuming that you are familiar and relatively comfortable with the definitions of mean, variance, and covariance, and understand the difference between a parameter and its estimator.

First, recall that:

> σ<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup> = E[(X-μ<sub>x</sub>)<sup>2</sup>] = E[X<sup>2</sup>] - E[X]<sup>2</sup>.

Similarly:

> Cov(X,Y) = E[(X-μ<sub>X</sub>)(Y-μ<sub>Y</sub>)] = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y].

Notice, in fact, that this means variance is just a special case of covariance, i.e., Var(X) = Cov(X,X)!

On to estimation.  The maximum likelihood estimator for variance is basically found by averaging data corresponding to the terms in the rightmost equalities above.  The variance estimator is:

> s<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup> = (Sum(x<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>) - n * (x_bar<sup>2</sup>)) / n

where n is the sample size and x_bar is the average of the sample of x's.  (Divide by (n-1) rather than n if you prefer the unbiased estimator to the MLE.)  Given the relationship between variance and covariance pointed out above, it shouldn't surprise you to find that the MLE estimator for covariance is:

> c = (Sum(x<sub>i</sub> * y<sub>i</sub>) - n * x_bar * y_bar) / n

Which leads us to your objective:

> s<sub>x+y</sub><sup>2</sup> = s<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup> + s<sub>y</sub><sup>2</sup> + 2 * c,

and from here you just take the square root to get standard deviation.

In pseudo-code:

```
function std_dev_sum(x_vector, y_vector):
  n = x_vector.length
  fail "different size vectors" unless y_vector.length == n   
  sum_x = sum_y = sum_x_sqr = sum_y_sqr = sum_xy = 0.0
  for each index i:
    x = x_vector[i]
    y = y_vector[i]
    sum_x += x
    sum_y += y
    sum_x_sqr += x * x
    sum_y_sqr += y * y
    sum_xy += x * y
  x_bar = sum_x / n
  y_bar = sum_y / n
  var_x = sum_x_sqr / n - x_bar * x_bar
  var_y = sum_y_sqr / n - y_bar * y_bar
  cov = sum_xy / n - x_bar * y_bar
  return Sqrt(var_x + var_y + 2.0 * cov)
```